# How do I apply a fade effect to this text?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have this simple HTML and CSS which swaps which `span` is visible when hovering over it.

I would like to add a fade effect to this, but I added `transition: ease-in-out 1s;` and nothing happened. Am I being really dumb?

```css
div#text1 span#s1main {
  display: inline;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1main {
  display: none;
}

div#text1 span#s1morph {
  display: none;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1morph {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">
  <span id="s1main">Hello World</span>
  <span id="s1morph">Secondary Text</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Umm dispay none wouldnt work with transition, you might have to play with opacity and position of the element to get it working.

```css
div#text1 span#s1main {
  opacity:1;
  transition: 1s all;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1main {
  opacity:0;
}

div#text1 span#s1morph {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  opacity:0;
  transition: 1s all;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1morph {
  opacity:1;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="text1">
  <span id="s1main">Hello World</span>
  <span id="s1morph">Secondary Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `position`! That's what I am missing! I couldn't figure out how to make it work how I wanted without `display`. Thanks a lot for reminding me!

Comment: Ugh. The secondary text now goes outside of my div when I hover over it thanks to absolute! I might have to use script, thanks anyway!

Comment: This works, but the text overlaps during the transition. If you want them to fade in sequentially, check out my demo.

Comment: I had to put `position:relative` into the main div, it now works, but has a little margin on the left when `secondary text` fades in. I can put up with it though!

Comment: May be you can give both secondary and primary texts absolute positioning that way they both stay in the same spot and no jump between transitions.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the property that you want to transition. For example:

```
transition: width 250ms ease-in-out;
```

or you can apply to all:

```
transition: all 250ms ease-in-out;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

And as Chiller said display is not an animatable property and you must do it with opacity.

Answer (score 1):

`display` can’t be transitioned
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#animatable-css

You would need to toggle the opacity of the words instead. Here’s a demo:

```css
#text1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Text 1 */
#text1 #s1main {
  transition: max-width 0s linear 250ms, visibility 0s linear 250ms, opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Text 2 */
#text1 #s1morph {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;/* for screen readers */
  transition: max-width 0s linear 250ms, visibility 0s linear 250ms, opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Text 1 Hover */
#text1:hover #s1main {
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;/* for screen readers */
  transition: max-width 0s linear 250ms, visibility 0s linear 250ms, opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}

/* Text 2 Hover */
#text1:hover #s1morph {
  max-width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-width 0s linear 250ms, visibility 0s linear 250ms, opacity 250ms ease-in-out 250ms;
  visibility: visible;/* for screen readers */
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">
  <span id="s1main">Hello World</span>
  <span id="s1morph">Secondary Text</span>
</div>
```

This demo uses multiple transitions and the `transition-delay` property to hide the words after the opacity transition has finished.

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea this was the case! Will be bookmarking that article!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use transition for the property display. you can use it for opacity

```css
div#text1 span#s1main {
  transition:opacity 1s;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:1;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1main {
   opacity:0;
}

div#text1 span#s1morph {
  transition:opacity 1s;
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
}

div#text1:hover span#s1morph {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="text1">
  <span id="s1main">Hello World</span>
  <span id="s1morph">Secondary Text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot I had to use `position` to make hiding a `div` work how I wanted it too!

Comment: I'm glad it helped you

Comment: `position` is not necessary to transition the opacity ;)

Comment: I used it to position one on top of the other not for transition.